# flutter two packages conflict

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

I'm trying to use date_picker_timeline saying :

***pubspec.YAML***

```yaml
dependencies:
  bottom_navy_bar: ^6.0.0
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.18
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  dash: ^1.0.3
  drop_down_list: ^0.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.20
  firebase_core: ^1.18.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_secure_storage: ^5.0.2
  flutter_signin_button: ^2.0.0
  google_fonts: ^3.0.1
  google_sign_in: ^5.4.0
  line_icons: ^2.0.1
  provider: ^6.0.3
  snippet_coder_utils: ^1.0.8
  date_picker_timeline:
```

```
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/date_picker_timeline-1.2.3/lib/date_picker_widget.dart:104:8: Error: Can't declare a member that conflicts with an inherited one.
  void initState() {
       ^^^^^^^^^

/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/date_picker_timeline-1.2.3/lib/date_picker_widget.dart:128:20: Error: The method 'call' isn't defined for the class 'void'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'call'.
    super.initState();
```

my datepiker method

```dart
DatePicker datePickerMethod() {
  return DatePicker(
    DateTime.now(),
    controller: dp,
    initialSelectedDate: DateTime.now(),
    selectionColor: Colors.blueAccent,
    selectedTextColor: Colors.white,
  );
}
```

already tried to flutter clear alson to delet puspec.lock not working

Comment: date_picker_timeline `Published 16 months ago •`, you might use others package who is computable on flutter v3. Also try  `date_picker_timeline:any`

Comment: what other packages can i use

Comment: I am not sure about, but you can fork and update the changes on that package too

Comment: i need to get that scrollable date https://imgur.com/a/HMziekZ